# Convert List of tuple of binary to string

Tags: erlang

I want to convert from

```
[{<<"Location">>,[{<<"lat">>,123456},{<<"lng">>,123456}]}]
```

to

```
"[{<<"Location">>,[{<<"lat">>,123456},{<<"lng">>,123456}]}]"
```

in Erlang.

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Comment: Ok, i am creating 1 string and i want to add [{<<"Location">>,[{<<"lat">>,123456},{<<"lng">>,123456}]}] as a string  in main string so i am converting this list to string and generate a new string.. and this list is decode json part in erlang

Comment: @ankiitsavaliya You are still not showing what did you tried. Edit your question and show what **exactly** have you tried and what error you got and what **exactly** you expect. We can't be sure what **exactly** you mean by words:  _creating_,  _string_, _add_, _main string_, _converting this list_, _new string_, _lists is decode_, ... It all makes very little sense. Show your code and your attempt in the text of the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you can't have double quotes inside double quotes so you must use an escape \"

Use

```
lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [ [{<<"Location">>,[{<<"lat">>,123456},{<<"lng">>,123456}]}] ])).
```